# Taking $\lim$ or $\sup$ of $\{f_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When we take a limit or sup of a sequence of real-valued functions $\{f_n(x)\}$, are we necessarily fixing $x$?

For a fixed $x$, we get a set of real numbers. So taking the limit or supremum on this set makes sense.

Is this a valid interpretation?

For example, consider the following set L: for a given $a\in\mathbb{R}$,

$$L=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\sup_n f_n(x)>a\}.$$

In this case, we are looking at a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\sup_n f_n(x)>a$. Hence, for each $x$, we look at a set of numbers $\{f_n(x)\}$ and see if its supremum is strictly greater than $a$. Is this a correct "timing" of interpreting the set $L$?

Comment: Notice that $\sup$ and $\inf$ are _order_ operations, i.e. they depend on what you mean by $\leq$ on $\mathbb{R}$. It makes sense to define orders on functions as well, and so you may define $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ on functions spaces. Though for the most part $\limsup_n f_n$ means pointwise limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation of $L$ is correct.

Also note that $L=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f_n(x)>a\}$